# How to use Django forms' get_initial_for_field() method?

Tags: python, django

I have two models `Company` and `Package`, defined as follows:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    default_package = models.OneToOneField(
        Package,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='default_for_%(class)s')


class Package(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('lucy_web.Company')
```

where `lucy_web` is the name of the app. So there is a many-to-one relationship between `Package` and `Company`, and additionally, a one-to-one relationship between a `Company` and its `default_package`.

I'm making a `ModelForm` for the `Package` object, of which a simplified version is

```
class PackageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = [
            'is_default',
        ]

    is_default = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, required=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        package = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.cleaned_data['is_default']:
            package.company.default_package = package
            package.company.save()
        return package
```

So when `is_default` is set to `True`, the package gets set to its company's default package.

The problem is that this form is used in both a generic `CreateView` and and `UpdateView`, and in the `UpdateView`, the `is_default` is still set to `True` even if the package is not the default package. This would make it easy for a user to inadvertently change a package to default when actually they just want to change another field.

I would like to make the `initial` for `is_default` such that it is `True` for unbound forms, and for bound forms, is `True` only when the `package` has a `default_for_company`. I tried to add this to the `__init__()`, like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance and self.instance.default_for_company:
        self.initial['is_default'] = True
```

Unfortunately, however, for a package that is not the default, this leads to a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error:

```
File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/dashboard/forms/packages.py" in __init__
  60.         if self.instance and self.instance.default_for_company:

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  407.                     self.related.get_accessor_name()

Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /dashboard/packages/55
Exception Value: Package has no default_for_company.
```

Also, overriding the `__init__()` seems a bit 'hacky' and it would seem that the [`get_inital_for_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.get_initial_for_field) method is designed for this purpose. Is this something I can define for my `PackageForm` to 'dynamically' get initial values for the fields in this way? (It was unclear to me from the docs how to apply it in this case).

Comment: Note that your wording "such that it is True for unbound forms, and for bound forms, is True" doesn't really make sense. Initial data is only used for `unbound` forms. Perhaps you mean for creating/updating instances.

Comment: Another option would be to override `get_initial()` for your `UpdateView`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach of overriding the `__init__` method looks OK to me. Use `hasattr` to avoid the `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` exception.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance and hasattr(self.instance, 'default_for_company'):
        self.initial['is_default'] = True
```

I haven't used `get_initial_for_field` before. It looks like you could do something like:

```
def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):
    if field_name == 'is_default':
        return bool(self.instance and hasattr(self.instance, 'default_for_company'))
    return super().get_initial_for_field(field, field_name)
```

Comment: The latter approach seems to work, thanks! The only remaining issue I have is that for the `CreateView` (the form for new packages), `is_default`'s `initial` is not set to `True`. I've noticed that in this case actually `self.initial` is an empty dictionary, so I could special-case it, but could there be a better way?

Comment: `get_initial_for_field` worked fine with a `CreateView` when I tried it, so you just need to make sure you get the right logic in your method. Checking `self.instance.pk` is the typical way to check whether you are creating or updating a model instance.